# Why destructor is not getting called for anonymous objects?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, copy-constructor, anonymous

While working, I came across one strange/confusing piece of code which I feel is related to **anonymous** **object** life cycle concept. Below is the sample piece of code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

class A {
private:
    int i;
    std::string s;
public:
    A(int ii, std::string ss = "Hello") { i = ii; s = ss; }
    void Display() { std::cout<<i<<"\n"; }
    ~A() { std::cout<<"A::~A()"<<"\n";}
};

void function()
{
    A a = 1;
    //A a = A(1);
    a.Display();
}

int main()
{
    function();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output1(If A a = 1) in VS2010**

```
 1
  A::~A()
```

**Output2(If A a = A(1)) in VS2010**

```
A::~A()
1
A::~A()
```

The **output2** perfectly make sense as **destructor** gets called twice(including for anonymous) object.

However **output1** confuses me and not able to understand why **destructor** is getting called once(not for anonymous) object.

```
A a = 1;
```

Above line would calls the copy-constructor(`A(const A& rhs)`) of class `A` and for which compiler should create the anonymous object using parameter `1`. If that is the case destructor should gets called twice.

Could somebody explains me about this behavior?. May be I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`A a = A(1);` is equivalent to `A a = 1;`. However, in both cases, [copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) may occur: The `A(1)` is actually constructed directly into `a`, instead of being constructed separately and then copied or moved.

It's up to the compiler to decide whether or not to perform copy elision in any of its permitted scenarios (as described in the above link).

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler is eliding the copy for `A a = 1`, but not for `A a = A(1);`, gcc is able to [elide](https://ideone.com/zMTPDf) the copy in both cases, this can be tested with `-fno-elide-constructors`.

Comment: fno-elide-constructors flag was very useful to understand this.